# SQL NOT LIKE comparison against dynamic list

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

Working on a new TSQL Stored Procedure, I am wanting to get all rows where values in a specific column don't start with any of a specific set of 2 character substrings.

The general idea is:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE value NOT LIKE 's1%' AND value NOT LIKE 's2%' AND value NOT LIKE 's3%'`.

The catch is that I am trying to make it dynamic so that the specific substrings can be pulled from another table in the database, which can have more values added to it.

While I have never used the `IN` operator before, I think something along these lines should do what I am looking for, however, I don't think it is possible to use wildcards with `IN`, so I might not be able to compare just the substrings.

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE value NOT IN (SELECT substrings FROM subTable)`

To get around that limitation, I am trying to do something like this:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE SUBSTRING(value, 1, 2) NOT IN (SELECT Prefix FROM subTable WHERE Prefix IS NOT NULL)`

but I'm not sure this is right, or if it is the most efficient way to do this.  My preference is to do this in a Stored Procedure, but if that isn't feasible or efficient I'm also open to building the query dynamically in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option.  Load values you want to filter to a table, left outer join and use [PATINDEX()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

```
DECLARE @FilterValues TABLE
    (
        [FilterValue] NVARCHAR(10)
    );

--Table with values we want filter on.
INSERT INTO @FilterValues (
                              [FilterValue]
                          )
VALUES ( N's1' )
     , ( N's2' )
     , ( N's3' );

DECLARE @TestData TABLE
    (
        [TestValues] NVARCHAR(100)
    );

--Load some test data
INSERT INTO @TestData (
                          [TestValues]
                      )
VALUES ( N's1 Test Data' )
     , ( N's2 Test Data' )
     , ( N's3 Test Data' )
     , ( N'test data not filtered out' )
     , ( N'test data not filtered out 1' );


SELECT          a.*
FROM            @TestData [a]
LEFT OUTER JOIN @FilterValues [b]
    ON PATINDEX([b].[FilterValue] + '%', [a].[TestValues]) > 0
WHERE           [b].[FilterValue] IS NULL;
```

Comment: Interesting... I've never used ```PATINDEX()``` or ```IN``` before, so I may need to play with both of them.  Does either one have a performance benefit over the other?

Comment: You'll probably see similar performance.  Test and check your execution plans.   The left outer with PATINDEX() would give you a little more flexibility if needed as you wouldn't be restricted to only evaluating the first 2 characters for the field you are checking.